# How can I find replacement parts for a Hyundai Sonata headlight assembly?

Tags: headlight, hyundai, sonata

My wife's sonata recently failed inspection because it has no parking light on the driver's side, and apparently no socket to hold the bulb (The assembly had previously been damaged and we installed a replacement we bought on ebay). I don't want to shell out another $200 for another assembly, it is possible to find just this one part?

Comment: Did you check a local auto part?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend going to the dealer for just the plug, as to avoid any wrong electrical parts. They should be able to order just that connector, or socket.